# Can we build and upload ios app with swift and objective-c mixed code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

Actually, I am working on one app and started with the objective-c. Now i have started working on swift with the same app for the further development and it will work with both the class (objc and swift).
Now I have doubt that it will accept by apple store or not.
Please help me.

Comment: of course, all you need is adding bridging header, have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call Objective C code from Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: Try watching the WWDC videos. Apple actively _encourages_ you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine, Apple provides the mechanisms for interacting with both and will not drop support for Objective-C for quite sometime. Many large organisations still have the majority of their code written in Obj-C (including Apple) so they need to give people time to transition, they aren't going to switch over immediately to a relatively immature language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Swift and Objective-c together. There is no issue in it. You need to create a bridging header file.

Please read this

[Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)